# Convert a https:// url to a file:// url

Tags: hyperlink, firefox-addon

I want my web browser to map a https:// url to a file:// url.  For example:

```
https://github.com/Derek-Jones/ESEUR-code-data/blob/master/group-compare/SW-check.R
file:///home/derek/ESEUR-code-data/group-compare/SW-check.R
```

The [redirector](https://github.com/einaregilsson/Redirector) browser add-on supports modification of http and https requests, but the API used by this add-on does not support mapping to a file:// request (the response to an issue I opened on the projects [github page](https://github.com/einaregilsson/Redirector/issues/213)).

The [pdf](http://www.knosof.co.uk/ESEUR/ESEUR-draft.pdf) of my [evidence-based software engineering book](http://www.knosof.co.uk/ESEUR/) includes links to the code+data on a Github repo, and currently requires an Internet connection to work.  It would be very useful if the links worked on machines that did not have an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you are running into because switching from `http://` to `file://`, could be considered a security issue.  Most modern browsers will flag this as a cross-domain request and not allow it.

Since you indicate that this is for a machine without internet access, you can actually create an alias that redirects `github.com` to a local web server, which can take the URL and parse it into a file reference and return the information being requested.  I have done this on numerous occasions and generally use Flask on python to perform the web server processing.  This actually may be a simpler and more robust solution.

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but is it really a bigger risk than allowing the complete url to be rewritten?  Yes, I could set up a local server, but I was after something simpler that less technical readers might also use.

Comment: The risk is because it opens up the possibility of someone injecting a "bad" URL into the data stream.  Now on an air-gapped network, this is more than likely, not an issue.  But for general.  For example, what if some took the `http://` URL you expect and changed it to one that would allow someone with nefarious goals, to download a file that should remain secure.

I see your goals and applaud them.  I have done exactly what you are suggesting back in the 90's.  It stopped working when the cross-domain issue was "fixed" by the browser providers.